# Dynamic library dependencies not recognized when run in parallel under R foreach()

Tags: r, linux, environment-variables, parallel-foreach

I'm using the `Rfast` package, which imports the package `RcppZiggurat`. I'm running R 3.6.3 on a Linux cluster (Red Hat 6.1). The packages are installed on my local directory but R is installed system-wide.

The Rfast functions (e.g. `colsums()`) work well when I call them directly. But when I call them in a `foreach()` loop like the following (EDIT: I added the code to register the cluster as pointed out by Rui Barradas but it didn't fix the problem).

```r
library(Rfast)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

A <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), 1000, 1000)
cm <- foreach(n = 1:4, .packages = 'Rfast') %dopar% colmeans(A)

stopCluster(cl)
```

then I get an error:

```
unable to load shared object '/home/users/sutd/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RcppZiggurat/libs/RcppZiggurat.so':
  libgsl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Somehow, the dynamic library is recognized when called directly but not when called under `foreach()`.

I know that `libgsl.so` is located in `/usr/lib64/`, so I've added the following line at the beginning of my R script

`Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH=paste("/usr/lib64/", Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"), sep = ":"))`

But it didn't work.

I have also tried to do `dyn.load('/usr/lib64/libgsl.so')` but I get the following error:

```
Error in dyn.load("/usr/lib64/libgsl.so") : unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/libgsl.so': 
/usr/lib64/libgsl.so: undefined symbol: cblas_ctrmv
```

**How do I make the dependencies available in the `foreach()` parallel loops?**

**NOTE**

In the actual use case I am using the genetic algorithm package `GA`, and have `GA::ga()` which handles the `foreach()` loop, and within the loop I use a function in my own package which calls the `Rfast` functions. So I'm hoping that there is **a solution where I don't have to modify the `foreach()` call**.

Comment: I have also tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64/`, and added `.packages = c('Rfast', 'RcppZiggurat')` in the `foreach()` call. Both failed.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling package `Rfast`?

Comment: Why are you double posting [as a GitHub issue](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppziggurat/issues/15) and here?

Comment: I am sorry, @DirkEddelbuettel. I posted the GitHub issue at a moment of weakness and frustration. I desperately need the code to work as I am submitting my thesis in a month. I have been trying to resolve dependencies for several days but they just keep popping up one after another, and I wanted to give up. But a few hours after posting the GitHub issue, having calmed down, I did some tests and realized that it is because of the parallel processing. So I thought posting here will be appropriate. I didn't realize that cross posting is not appropriate. Lesson learned. I apologise.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes I have tried to reinstall, first just `RcppZiggurat`, and then `Rfast`, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Other lesson learned is that SO gets more eyeballs so let's post here first. And yes---your issue appears to be a basic parallel computing one I covered in 'intro to HPC' slides a few times approximately 15 years ago: your work nodes need all the required packages loaded too.

Comment: Yes, I realize that now, but I don't know how. I've searched and tried many ways in vain. Could you please point me to where else I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers by @RuiBarradas and @coatless, I realize that the problem is not with `foreach()`, because (1) the problem occurred when I ran the code with `future` too, and (2) it occurred with the `foreach()` code even with the wrong call, when I didn't register the cluster. When there is no cluster registered, `foreach()` will throw a warning and runs in sequential mode instead. But that didn't happen.

Therefore, I realize that the problem must have occurred even before the `foreach()` call. In the log, it appeared right after the message `Loading package RcppZiggurat`. Something must have gone wrong when this package is loaded.

I then checked the dependencies of `RcppZiggurat`, and found that it depends on another package called `RcppGSL`, which interfaces R and the GSL library. Bingo, that's where `libgsl.so.0` is needed when RcppZiggurat is called.

So I made an R script named `test-gsl.R`, which has the following two lines.

```r
library(RcppZiggurat)
print(‘OK’)
```

Now, I run the following on the head node

```
$ module load R/3.6.3
$ Rscript test-gsl.R
```

And everything works fine. The ‘OK’ is printed.

But this doesn’t work if I submit the job on the compute node. First, the PBS script, called `test.sh`, is as follows

```
### Resources request
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=1:mem=1GB

### Walltime
#PBS -l walltime=00:01:00

echo Working directory is $PBS_O_WORKDIR
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

### Run R
module load R/3.6.3
Rscript test-gsl.R
```

Then I ran

```
qsub test.sh
```

And the error popped out. This means that there is something different between the compute node and the head node on my system, and nothing to do with the packages. I contacted the system administrator, who explained to me that the GSL library is available on the head node at the default path, but not on the compute node. So in my shell script, I need to add `module load gsl/2.1` before running my R script. I tested that and everything worked.

The solution seems simple enough, but I know very little about Linux administration to realize it. Only after asking around and trying (rather blindly) many things did I finally come to this solution. So thanks to those who've offered help, and mea culpa for not being able to describe the problem accurately at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

The following works with no problems. Unlike the code in the question, it starts by detecting the number of available cores, create a cluster and make it available to `foreach`.

```
library(Rfast)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

set.seed(2020)
A <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), 1000, 1000)
cm <- foreach(n = 1:4, 
              .combine = rbind, 
              .packages = "Rfast") %dopar% {
  colmeans(A)
}

stopCluster(cl)

str(cm)
#num [1:4, 1:1000] -0.02668 -0.02668 -0.02668 -0.02668 0.00172 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:4] "result.1" "result.2" "result.3" "result.4"
#  ..$ : NULL
```

Comment: I just tested, but this didn't work on my end, unfortunately. My example wasn't correct, and it accidentally reproduced the error. But in actual use case, `foreach()` is called from `GA::ga()`, which does the cluster registration by itself already. On Windows I didn't need to register separately, and the code just works. When I ported to Linux, it failed.

Comment: If your problem (@Drumy) is that `GA::ga` doesn't succefully export the libraries (which I would assume is a bug from the package), have you tried to 1) Update the package? 2) Overwriting the function definition, adding the export manually. This could be done manually using copy-paste of the function definition or by using `edit(GA::ga)`. There is only 1 call to `foreach` in the function itself, so it could be easy to fix.

Comment: Thank you Oliver. Yes the GA package is updated (in fact it is a fresh install). But I think it's not just GA, because manually exporting following Rui's code above also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` package was great for its time. But, now, parallel computations should be done with `future` just for the static code analysis handling the correct export to workers. As a result, under the `future` approach, registering a package with `.packages=` isn't needed. Moreover, the `future` mirrors usual *R* code with only a slight change regarding the setup of an output variable as a `listenv`. For example, we have:

```r
library("future")
library("listenv")
library("Rfast")

plan(tweak(multiprocess , workers = 2L))
# For all cores, directly use:
# plan(multiprocess)

# Generate matrix once
A <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), 1000, 1000)
# Setup output
x <- listenv()

# Iterate 4 times
for(i in 1:4) {
  # On each core, compute the colmeans()
  x[[i]] %<-% {
    colmeans(A)
    # For better control over function applies, use a namespace call
    # e.g. Rfast::colmeans(A)
  }
}

# Switch from listenv to list
output <- as.list(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I have just tried your code but the same error still occurred.

Comment: @Drumy I removed the `futureOf()` part. If you run the above code, what's the error?